# How to display array inside an array using - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hi guys i have a problem in displaying arrays...

This is my array.

```
[
  "ABM"   => [ ""    => [ ""  => 0 ] ],
  "GAS"   => [ "one" => [ "F" => 1 ] ],
  "HUMMS" => [ ""    => [ ""  => 0 ] ],
  "STEM"  => [ ""    => [ ""  => 0 ] ]
];
```

this is my code for that array :

```
$array = array();
$array[$p['CourseCode']][$p['YearLevel']][$p['Gender']]+=$p['count'];
```

and i want to display it here :

```
      ---ONE---   ---TWO---
CODE |  M  |  F  |  M  |  F  |
     |     |     |     |     |
```

if it is 'one' it will display the `COUNT` to ---ONE--- or else to ---TWO---

and if it is 'F' it will display the `COUNT` to F or else to M

Sorry for my limited english..and poor explanation im a just a newbie in programming.. Thanks

Comment: make your array fresh and readable....

Comment: @Frayne Konok how can i do that?

Comment: What did you mean by CODE??

Comment: @Frayne Konok ABM,GAS,HUMMS AND STEM

Comment: Check this out: [https://3v4l.org/LoGGk](https://3v4l.org/LoGGk)

Comment: @FrayneKonok thanks for editting

Comment: NO id did't do that for a long, I rollback fro it. First you need to ensure that you have that array or not.

Comment: You should use `var_export` instead of `print_r` to publish parsable code. Your code and intention are totally unclear to me. I can guess many things you try to achieve. Please clarify. How is the array generated? Do you retrieve it from a database?

Comment: @KUPSKIE, Check the answer. I think you will be benefited...

Comment: Thanks for the info and help guys...Problem Solved :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want something like

```
<?php

$data =
[
  "ABM"   => [ ""    => [ ""  => 0 ] ],
  "GAS"   => [ "one" => [ "F" => 1 ] ],
  "HUMMS" => [ ""    => [ ""  => 0 ] ],
  "STEM"  => [ ""    => [ ""  => 0 ] ],
  "COL1"  => [ "one" => [ ""  => 1 ] ],
  "COL2"  => [ "one" => [ "F" => 2 ] ],
  "COL3"  => [ ""    => [ ""  => 3 ] ],
  "COL4"  => [ ""    => [ "F" => 4 ] ],
];


$rows = [];
foreach($data as $key=>$arr)
{ 
  $row = array_fill(0, 5, '');
  $row[1+( ( ('one' !== key($arr))<<1 ) | ( 'F' === key(current($arr)) ) )] = '' . current(current($arr));
  $row[0] = $key;
  $rows[] = $row;
}

?>

<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr> <td rowspan="2"></td> <td colspan="2"> ONE </td> <td colspan="2"> TWO </td> </tr>
    <tr>                       <td>M</td> <td>F</td>      <td>M</td> <td>F</td> </tr>
<?php foreach($rows as &$row): ?>
    <tr>
<?php   foreach($row as &$col): ?>
      <td><?php echo $col; ?></td>
<?php   endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Explaination**
We have a stacked array as data source for each row. The keys decide in which column the value is filled in.

> (**one**|*two*) => (*M*|**F**) => value

This looks like a binary tree. Let's think the column *one/M* were number 0 and the last column 'two/F' number 3. That means *one* results in 0 or 1 and *two* in 2 or 3, or say:

> *one*: **0 + (0 or 1)**
>
> *two*: **2 + (0 or 1)**

If **+0** or **+1** is decided by *M or F*. In binary numbers it looks like that:

> 0 = 00
>
> 1 = 01
>
> 2 = 10

Since the bits in this numbers have unique positions, we can just use a binary OR disjunction instead of addition, that's `|` in PHP, which the CPU will process faster.

A logical comparison results in true or false evaluating to the integers 1 and 0. `('one' !== key($arr))` is true/1 when the key something other than "one", means *two*. `01` bitshifted left is `10` (decimal 2). This is done by `<< bit_count` in PHP. Dependend on *M/F* a 0 or 1 is added (OR-disjunction). We have our index from 0 to 3. Since we want the "CODE" in column 0, we add 1 to the calculated data column index and store the "CODE" in column 0.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to design the table for you, but here is the functions...

You need to some loop here, use 3 `foreach loop` for access the last depth of the array.

```
$arr = [
  "ABM"   => [ ""    => [ ""  => 0 ] ],
  "GAS"   => [ "one" => [ "F" => 1 ] ],
  "HUMMS" => [ ""    => [ ""  => 0 ] ],
  "STEM"  => [ ""    => [ ""  => 0 ] ]
];


foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    echo 'Code: '.$key."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    foreach($value as $k1 => $v1){
        if($k1 == "one")
            echo 'ONE: '.$k1."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        else
            echo 'TWO: '.$k1;       
        foreach($v1 as $k2 => $v2){
            if($k2 == 'F')
                echo 'Gender: F - '.$v2."<br/>";
            else
                echo 'Gender: M - '.$v2."<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Code: ABM     TWO:       Gender: M - 0
Code: GAS     ONE: one   Gender: F - 1
Code: HUMMS   TWO:       Gender: M - 0
Code: STEM    TWO:       Gender: M - 0
```

Comment: Thanks @Frayne Konok

Comment: Welcome, I know you can design your desire `table / div` from this code. Wish you all the best.